# laravel 5.6 not reading variable from controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel so pardon me if this question seems stupid. I am trying to do a basic CRUD app, the create and read seems to work fine but am having issues with editing, updating and deleting. When I click the edit button it returns undefined variable log_books but to my understanding I think I have declared it. Please help.

controller name: logbook.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\log_book;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class logbook extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    /**
    *
    *@if(Auth::check())
    */

    $log_books = log_book::all();
    return view('home')->with('log_books',$log_books);

    /**
    *
    *@endif
    */

}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //

/**
 *
 *   @if(Auth::check())
 */
        return view('log_books.create');
/**
 *
 *   @endif
 */
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    log_book::create(Request::all());
    return redirect('home')->with('message','name has been added successfully');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    /**
     *
     *@if(Auth::check())
     */

    $log_books = log_book::findorFail($id);
    //$logs = DB::table('log_books')->where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('log_books.edit', compact($log_books))->with('id', $id);

    /**
     *
     *@endif
     */


}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
    $log_books = log_books::findorFail($id);

    $destroy = $log_books->delete();

    if($destroy) {
        return redirect('home', compact($log_books))->with('message', 'Record has been deleted');
    }
}
}
```

My Route: web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('create', function () {
return view('create');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/create', 'logbook@create')->name('create');
Route::post('store', 'logbook@store');
Route::get('/home', 'logbook@index');
Route::get('edit/{id}', 'logbook@edit');
Route::delete('destroy/{id}', 'logbook@destroy');
```

My View: home.blade.php

```
 @foreach($log_books as $row)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$row->present_date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$row->time_in}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$row->time_out}}</td>
                                        <td><a href="{{ URL::to('edit',$row->id) }}"><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit"></a>&nbsp;<a href="{{ URL::to('destroy',$row->id) }}"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"></a></td>
                                    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

edit view: edit.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="edit">
                    {{csrf_field()}}

                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
                    <input required="yes" type="text" placeholder="Full name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$log_books->name}}"><br>
                    <input required="yes" onfocus="this.type= 'date'" onblur="this.type='text'" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" name="present_date" value="{{$log_books->present_date}}"><br>
                    <input required="yes" onfocus="this.type= 'time'" onblur="this.type='text'" placeholder="Time in" class="form-control" name="time_in" value="{{$log_books->time_in}}"><br>
                    <input onfocus="this.type= 'time'" onblur="this.type='text'" placeholder="Time out" class="form-control" name="time_out" value="{{$log_books->time_out}}"><br>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Pardon my code if it looks messed up, the create and edit view are both in a folder called log_books. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your controller, instead of using `return view('home')->with('log_books',$log_books);` have you tried using the `compact` function? It would be like this: `return view('home', compact('log_books'))`

Comment: The index function in the controller works fine. But it keeps bringing up "undefined variable log_books" when it is about to open the edit.blade.php view which is connected to the edit function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in your controller, before you return the view, what does `$log_books` output? Can you place a `dd($log_books);` before you return the view to make sure that `log_book::all();` isn't returning `undefined`?

Comment: The view for the home or the view for the edit or create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `edit` method is passing an invalid value to compact:

```
return view('log_books.edit', compact($log_books))->with('id', $id);
```

Should most likely be the 'name' of the variable you want to compact, not the variable itself:

```
return view('log_books.edit', compact('log_books'))->with('id', $id);
```

To avoid these types of mistakes completely, just define the array:

```
return view('log_books.edit', ['log_books' => $log_books])...
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has Route model binding, you may use this feature in `show` and `edit` methods as follows:

**In Controller**

```
public function edit(Log_Book $log_book)
{
    return view('log_books.edit', compact($log_book));
}
```

**In web.php**

```
Route::get('/edit/{log_book}', 'logbook@edit');
```

Also you don't need to check auth in controller methods, use `auth` middleware.

**In Controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    return $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. edit.blade.php still gives the same error.